# How to restrict a user from using tty?

Tags: centos, tty, logout, pts

i was wondering if it is possible to force log out a user (anyone other than root) when trying to login via tty (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>/<kbd>f2</kbd>/<kbd>f3</kbd>..). The user should be able to use pts with no problems.
Using CentOS 7.

Comment: Please add Linux distribution to the question.

Comment: `pam_access` should be able to take care of that. See `man pam_access` and `man access.conf`.

Comment: This question is unclear.  It could be that it is asking how to prevent non-superusers from logging on on virtual terminals.  It could be that it is asking how to kick other non-superuser users off when someone logs on on a virtual terminal.  It can be read either way.

Answer (score 1):

You can add entries to `/etc/security/access.conf` which disallow logins to the TTYs like so:

```
-:ALL EXCEPT root
```

There's other examples in this file if you're looking for additional use cases. **NOTE:** The above says to remove ALL except root.

#### References

- [CentOS / RHEL 7 : How to disable all tty consoles and enable only 1](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-restrict-users-access-on-a-linux-machine)
- [How to restrict users access on a Linux machine](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-restrict-users-access-on-a-linux-machine)
- [access.conf (5) - Linux Man Pages](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-access.conf/)